# Installing Adobe After Effects without the administrator rights

Tags: administrator, adobe, sandbox

I'd like to get a one year license for After Effects and start learning it but in the past I've installed the trial and it was requiring an administrator password. It then added all kind of processes at startup, a thing I'd like to avoid (and I'm in general bothered it asks for the admin rights for what it does).

Is there a way to sandbox it or any other way to avoid this?

Comment: Adobe's installers.... GAH... The problem with installing any Adobe software is that it *requires* Creative Cloud, which then requires an internet connection. Depending on your Mac and OS version you might want to look into lightweight virtualization and run After Effects on a VM that you don't care how badly Adobe's installer will mess things up... just a thought...

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yeah, not the same thing. Wireshark requires admin rights too, I'm fine with that. Hope you see the difference.

Comment: The moment an application needs to add/modify files that are in sensitive areas, you need Admin rights. Adobe CC requires this and there is no workaround, unfortunately.